# SQL query to get all except where id is in array that comes from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I could use some help with some SQL. Part of a website that I need to do is a place where you can add/remove stores from users. Now the query to get the stores that have already been assigned to a certain user is simple, however I can't seem to figure out how to do the opposite. Meaning getting all that haven't been added to the user yet.

So here's a template of 1 of the tables.

```
    user_id  store_id
    1        11 
    1        12
    1        14
    2        15
    4        16
```

If I run this (that 1 will be php variable): `SELECT store_id FROM store_user WHERE user_id= 1;`
I get the result like that:

```
store_id
11
12
14
```

And the rest would be something like: `SELECT * FROM store except where id = 11,12,14`.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me with that last part and preferrably put it all in to 1 query.

Edit: for those who stumble here with a similar problem, this is what worked in the end:

```
SELECT * FROM store where id NOT IN (select store_id from store_user where user_id = 1)
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: You want the rows where id <> 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `NOT IN`

```
SELECT * FROM store where 
id NOT IN (select store_id from store_user where user_id = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what I meant was I want to put the result from 1st SQL to the other one so it would be dynamic (so when I put the variable in in php, it would give me all the stores that haven't been assigned to it).

Comment: try this query     SELECT * FROM store
    where id IN 
    (select store_id from store where user_id = 1) @Rauno

Comment: Thank you, that was almost correct but it solved the problem for me anyway. The end result that worked was this: SELECT * FROM store where id NOT IN (select store_id from store_user where user_id = 1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **IN** or **NOT IN**

```
select store_id from store where id in (1,2....)
select store_id from store where id not in (1,2....)
```